# Android C2DM works with Web Service java-based, but 401 Error comes out if i try in a WS dotNet-based

Tags: android, .net, iis-7, android-c2dm, httpwebresponse

i did a simple Web Service in Java and i deployed it in JBOSS 5.1.
This WS handles C2DM service for sending a notify message to an Android phone. I set all like i red in google c2dm api, and, first of all, i sign up for accessing to c2dm service. In this case, all works well.

Now i have to do the same in .NET on IIS7. Some clarification about the .Net code:

- setRegId() and pushMessage() method are available by WebService.
- handShakeRegId() is simply called by setRegId() after String "reg_id" and "device_id" are setted
- all code commented are my try for solving problem, but all was useless

Thats the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WebService1
{

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    private String accountType = "HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE";
    private String email = "example@gmail.com";
    private String password = "password";
    private String service = "ac2dm";
    private String source = "com.cloudTest.app";
    private String HTTPHeaderCT = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    private String auth;
    private String reg_Id;
    private String deviceId;
    private String collapseKey = "CollapseKey";

    public void handShakeRegId()
    {

        HttpWebRequest req;
        Stream reqst;
        try
        {
            req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");

         //   string proxy = null;
         //   req.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
         //   req.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4;
         //   req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            string data = String.Format("accountType={0}&Email={1}&Passwd={2}&service={3}&source={4}", accountType, email, password, service, source);

            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
         //   ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
         //   byte[] buffer = encoding.GetBytes(data);

            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = HTTPHeaderCT;
            req.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
          //  req.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy, true);
          //  req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            reqst = req.GetRequestStream(); // add form data to request stream
            reqst.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("--------------------");
            Debug.Write("(handShakeRegId) Request Error:" + e);
            Debug.WriteLine("--------------------");
            throw;
        }

        HttpWebResponse res;
        Stream resst;
        try
        {
            res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            resst = res.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resst, Encoding.UTF8);
            string response = sr.ReadToEnd();

            string SID = response.Substring((response.IndexOf("SID=") + 4),
            (response.IndexOf("\n") - 4));//extracting SID

            string Auth = response.Substring((response.IndexOf("Auth=") + 5),
            (response.Length - (response.IndexOf("Auth=") + 5)) - 1);//extracting Auth

            auth = Auth;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Write("(handShakeRegId) Response Error:" + e);
            throw;
        }

        resst.Flush();
        resst.Close();
        reqst.Flush();
        reqst.Close();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public void setRegId(String reg_id, String device_id)
    {

        reg_Id = reg_id;
        deviceId = device_id;

        Debug.WriteLine("RegID=" + reg_Id);
        Debug.WriteLine("--------------------");
        Debug.WriteLine("DeviceID=" + deviceId);

        handShakeRegId();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public void pushMessage(String msg)
    {
        // Needed! Without an SSL Exception comes out
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate(object sender,
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
        System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };

        HttpWebRequest req;
        Stream reqst;

        try
        {

            req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");
            //req.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
            //req.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4;
            //req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            //req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("example@gmail.com","password");
            //req.KeepAlive = true;

            //string proxy = null;


            string data = String.Format("registration_id={0}&collapse_key={1}&data.message={2}", reg_Id, collapseKey, msg);

           // ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
           // byte[] buffer = encoding.GetBytes(data);

            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = HTTPHeaderCT;
            req.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
            req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=" + auth);

           // req.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy, true);
           // req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            reqst = req.GetRequestStream(); // add form data to request stream
            reqst.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Write("(PushMessageMsgOUT)Error: " + e);
            throw;
        }

        HttpWebResponse res;
        Stream resst;

        try
        {
            res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            HttpStatusCode responseCode = ((HttpWebResponse)res).StatusCode;
            if (responseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) || responseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Unauthorized - need new token");
            }
            else if (!responseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Response from web service not OK :");
                Debug.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)res).StatusDescription);
            }

            resst = res.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resst);

            string response = sr.ReadToEnd();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("(pushMessageMsgIN) Error: "+e);
            throw;
        }

        resst.Flush();
        resst.Close();
        reqst.Flush();
        reqst.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

- Handshake method works well! I get auth token without problem.
- setRegId method is called by Android device (in my case is the Android+GoogleApi 2.2 emulator)

Error which comes out is always the same in pushMessage getResponse() ( and its strange because i implement connection exactly like its in handshake method :-/ ):

*A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
(pushMessageMsgIN) Error: System.Net.WebException: remote server error (401) Unauthorized in System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()*

2 days for searching something useful but.... NOTHING!!
Its very stressful...

I hope someone can help me.

I red something about Authentication in IIS, so i enabled Anonymous User and other unknown things just for trying. Nothing!

Comment: HEEEEELPPPP !!!!!!!!!!!! PLSSSSSSSS

Comment: Noone can help me. uffff

Comment: i assume u stored ur auth token somewhere. you can't just reference like that.
I'm assuming ur auth token is null when you call  pushMessage().

Comment: Solved: MY STUPIDITY !!! i made a mistake in private String source !! I specified a wrong app package name! Haaa :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: MY STUPIDITY !!! i made a mistake in private String source !! I specified a wrong package name! -.-